# Permalinks are not working in Wordpress in digitalocean

Tags: php, apache

I deployed My Wordpress Blog in one of my subdomains in Digital Ocean. I am running apache2 as my webserver.

When I am trying to change my permalink settings to settings other than plain(Only plain setting is working), I am getting 404 Page

404 page

Can anyone help to fix this problem?

I tried activating mods)_rewrite module - apache and tried to create new .htaccess file in the wordpress root folder.

.htaccess file related to my WordPress installation:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

# END WordPress
Virtual host file related to Wordpress Site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.gopibabu.live
    ServerAlias www.blog.gopibabu.live

    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyBlog

        <Directory /var/www/MyBlog>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blog.gopibabu.live [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.blog.gopibabu.live
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I need my permalinks to work in my WordPress installation !!!

Comment: I would start by asking if you are using wordpress default twenty* themes? or a custom theme? Sometimes custom themes have CPT or related slug changes that cause issue. if you are using custom theme, please switch to the base theme and see if that works?

Comment: Switching to Default Theme didn't fix the issue with permalinks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my issue with permalinks :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaL72Ho_Fr8

**NOTE**: In my case, I edited the virtual hosts files for both HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: This work for me great save my time Thanks